# Firefox - Open specific link in all tabs?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

I'm looking for a Firefox addon that will let me open a bunch of tabs like this:

```
www.website.com/user.php?num=350
www.website.com/user.php?num=241
www.website.com/user.php?num=125
```

And then click a button to open a *specific* link on each page. For instance say there is a link on each one of those pages that is always in the same place that takes you to another section of the website so the result would be like:

```
www.website.com/details.php?num=350
www.website.com/details.php?num=241
www.website.com/details.php?num=125
```

For example, if I have a bunch of superuser.com questions open in tabs then I want to press a button and then have each tab "click" the link that goes to the OP of the question's user page.

Or say if I have a bunch of google search results open in multiple tabs I want each tab to open the link to the first result on the respective tab pages.

Any such add-on exist? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this would be too niche a requirement for an extension to exist.  You need to define which tabs are included, and how the link you are referring to should be identified.

**External**

Perhaps an alternative approach might be to use something like [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), where you define a hot key that did something like:

1. Focus firefox
2. Alt-1 for first tab
3. Focus page area
4. Press tab 'n' times, where n takes the focus to the correct link
5. Press enter (opens link)
6. Ctrl-tab to go to next tab
7. Go to 3 until all tabs actioned

**Extension Based**

If you'd prefer a extension based solution, then the [vimperator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimperator/) extension allows for macros to be written that can control firefox, and so could be used to drive the sequence you are after

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for...

Comment: Care to elaborate?  I have added an extension based option.

Comment: I see the extension you shared but I don't understand how to use it to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I faced a similar issue, and I think I have found a solution. Maybe it can still help you too: https://superuser.com/a/1807716/1841218

Comment: Please post the solution here as a quote and leave the link intact.

Comment: Why post it here as a quote? It is not an external link.