# Open links from multiple tabs in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, tabs

Please note I am not asking to simply open multiple tabs at once.

Essentially, I would like the functionality of the Link Gopher plugin, but I don't want to do it manually one tab at a time:

**I have a browser window full of tabs**, let's say they are support tickets. **The pages in these tabs all have a link** which is individual to each tab, but has a common, searchable element – for instance they link to a CRM page.

Now **I want to open all these CRM links** from the support ticket tabs. Either in their original tabs, or in new tabs, or just get them as a textual list.

Does such a Firefox plugin, or combination of plugins, exist? Or is there another way to do it? If it makes a difference, I'm on a Mac and I can use the Terminal if given idiot-proof instructions.

I have found [this old question](https://superuser.com/questions/1432256/in-firefox-how-can-i-filter-and-extract-multiple-links-located-within-multiple) looking for the same, but with no solution. Maybe something has sprung up in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have found a solution!**

This requires a combination of add-ons, and very few manual steps (which, crucially, will always be the same few steps regardless of number of tabs).

### Prerequisites

You need Firefox, the add-on "DownThemAll!", and an add-on that allows you to open multiple URLs from a list. There are many of those, and I don't know them well enough to recommend a specific one.

### Step-by-Step Instructions

Please note that the labels may be slightly different, as my system does not run in English.

1. With DownThemAll, choose *DownThemAll! - All Tabs*.
2. Ensure you are on the *Links* tab, not the *Media* tab.
3. Enter your search keyword in the *Quick Filter* text field (the first of the three text fields at the bottom)
4. Click *Add paused*. This will open a list of downloads, with the downloads not started. Which is good because we don't want to download. Don't worry if the names look strange.
5. Select all in this list, right click, choose *Export to file > Export as text*
6. Switch to your multiple-URL-opener plugin, and give it the list you just exported.

Voila! You have just opened as many links as you liked in just six steps. A more integrated solution would be nicer, but this is quite fine for me.